# Application failed to install in iPad2

Tags: ios5, titanium-mobile, ipad-2

My Application runs fine in iPad simulator, but when i try to install it in iPad 2.. It throws me Application Name Failed to install.

```
iOS version is 5.0.
```

I am using Titanium Mobile for development. The same Application works fine in Android emulator `and` device.

Comment: This message is usually related to code signing / application provisioning. check if you are signing the app with a valid developer certificate / distribution certificate with the right provisioning profile

Comment: Which titanium sdk is you are using ? Only SDk grater than 1.8 has iOS  5 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a developer certificate before you can deploy the application in iPad2.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Once you have got the certificate, you can right click on your project and select install on IOS device. It would ask to upload your dev certificate which you have got for your iPad. From there i see no problem in deploying your app.

This would generate an .ipa file.

Note: for iOS 5.0, you need to have 1.8 and above to make it work properly.